# IOError while Upgrade module odoo 10, how to solve this issue?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10

> IOError: File not found: /base/static/description/icon.png

Comment: Check the permission of this file

Comment: what is actual rights of file, i have tried --chmod 775 filename--

Comment: That is not enouph, try `ls -la` to check the owner `user:group`

Answer (score 0):

This is my suggestion for your question: 
     Just delete the **openerp**.py file and retype the code again, also restart the openerp server. This worked for me whenever I got this problem.

Technically, the error occurs @ action window (found by checking the code by eclipse debugger).

and check below link

https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/ioerror-file-not-found-17795

i hope it helps you